# Further thoughts on the energy estimate

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, inner-products

I put my [question about the energy estimate](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/32461/9464) two days ago. And finally I can get

$$\frac{d}{dt}\|x\|^2=2\|x\|\frac{d}{dt}\|x\|=\frac{d}{dt}\langle x,x \rangle=2Re\langle x, Ax\rangle$$

If I have the estimate $Re\langle x,Ax\rangle \leq 2\alpha\|x\|^2$ for some $\alpha\in{\bf R}$,
then I will get

$$\|x(t)\|\frac{d}{dt}\|x(t)\| \leq 2\alpha\|x(t)\|^2 \qquad\text{for all}\quad t\in {\bf R} \qquad(*)$$

Here are my **questions**:

1. Can one deduce from (*) that $\frac{d}{dt}\|x(t)\|\leq 2\alpha\|x(t)\|$ without worrying about that $x(t)=0$ may happen for some $t$?
2. If I can get $\frac{d}{dt}\|x(t)\|\leq 2\alpha\|x(t)\|$, can I use the method of solving the linear system $$\frac{d}{dt}\|x(t)\|= 2\alpha\|x(t)\|$$ to get $$\|x(t)\| \leq e^{2\alpha t}\|x(0)\|?$$

My thoughts on the second question:

Turn the inequalities $\frac{d}{dt}\|x(t)\|\leq 2\alpha\|x(t)\|$ into the non-homogeneous equation $\frac{d}{dt}\|x(t)\|= 2\alpha\|x(t)\|-\epsilon(t)$, then hopefully one can get the estimate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is much easier to just write

$$ \frac{d}{dt} \|x\|^2 \leq 4\alpha \| x(t) \|^2 $$

which then implies by [Gronwall's inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gronwall%27s_inequality)

$$ \|x(t)\|^2 \leq e^{4\alpha t} \|x(0)\|^2 $$

Now you can take square root.

Comment: Let me add the following general principle: when working over a Hilbert space, it is better to work with the squared norm, rather than just the norm itself. Why? the norm operator is not "differentiable" near 0. Think $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $x\mapsto |x|^2$ versus $x\mapsto |x|$.